# std::pair from temporary: Why is copy constructor called and not move constructor?

Tags: c++, move, std-pair

Consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A {
    A(const A&){
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
    }
    A(A&&){
        cout<<"move constructor"<<endl;
    }
    ~A(){
        cout<<"destructor"<<endl;
    }
    static std::pair<A,int> f1()
    {
        int i = 1;
        return std::pair<A,int>{i,2};
    }
    static std::pair<A,int> f2()
    {
        int i = 1;
        return std::pair<A,int>{A(i),2};
    }
    private:
    A(int){
        cout<<"constructor"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"f1: "<<endl;
    A::f1();
    cout<<"f2: "<<endl;
    A::f2();
}
```

The constructor `A(int)` is private, therefore the `A` in the `pair<A,int>` cannot be in place constructed from an `int`. Hence, a temporary is constructed in `f1`. In `f2` I create the temporary explicitly but the behavior is different, the output is:

```
f1: 
constructor
copy constructor
destructor
destructor
f2: 
constructor
move constructor
destructor
destructor
```

I would expect the move constructor to be called also in `A::f1` but the copy constructor is called which is sub optimal. Why is this the case?

Comment: It's better `A(int)`  is not private but is `explicit A(int)`. Then you get a better output `f1: \nconstructor\ndestructor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [pair's constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)

Interesting constructors are (2) and (3)

```
// (2)
constexpr pair( const T1& x, const T2& y );

// (3)
template< class U1 = T1, class U2 = T2 >
constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y ); // SFINAE on constructible
```

Notice, there are no `pair(T1&&, T2&&)`.

As `A(int)` is `private`, `std::is_constructible_v<A, int>` is `false`.

So for `f1`, only (2) is a viable constructor (so the copy).

For `f2`, (3) is viable (and better match), so a forward (so a move) is done.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in `f1` (3) is excluded as viable constructor and then implicit conversion is used to construct the temporary for (2). But if a temporary is constructed then (2) would be viable again right (because `std::is_constructible_v<A, A&&>` is `true`)?  (3) is just not considered anymore because it was excluded before? Is this a language design issue that could be improved theoretically by rechecking viability after potentially deciding for temporary construction?

Comment: Your explanation makes perfectly sense but I think it is strange that viability check does not consider implicit conversion before excluding options for template instantiation, especially when implicit conversion is used in the end as in this case (`f1`).

Comment: It is simpler to have one pass, especially in general case (`const char*`->`std::string`->`Person`->...)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why there is no `pair(T1&&, T2&&)` constructor?

Comment: You have to handle then the combination `(T1&&/const T2&)`, `T1&&/U2&&`, `U1/T2&&`, .. just to handle private (non-explicit) constructors... `U1&&/U2&&` does the job with public constructors.